# Making forms with decreasing number of selections after submission

Tags: forms, input, field

I'm trying to make my form remove an option or decrease the number of available options:

Example. Drop down.
Cheeseburgers (10 available)
Hamburger (1 available)
Big Mac (3 available)

User Chooses Cheesburgers and submits. I want the form to display this for the next user after submission.
Cheeseburgers (9 available)
Hamburger (1 available)
Big Mac (3 available)

Comment: In most cases a database is used for that purpose (upon form submission the quantity field in the record for cheeseburgers in the products table is modified and next time the form is shown the at that time current product records are read back from the table), so you may want to read some introductory material about how to use your scripting language of choice with a database.  In its present form not much more concrete info can be given I'm afraid.

Comment: I apologize for a broad question. I'm using Joomla 2.5 and RSForms extension at the moment. Obviously PHP. I'm capable of modifying it just need direction where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database with an entry for each option, and a counter that represents the total number left for each. Then you can just output the total number using php, and subtract one to the corresponding category when the form is submitted